# windows 7 environment variable isn't working

Tags: windows-7

```
 T:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
```

%PCP%

```
 T:\>echo %PCP%
```

C:\code\portal-hibernate\lib\third-party\hibernatev4.0\required;C:\code\portal-hibernate\src\BINGO;C:\code\portal-hibernate\lib\third-party

How come echoing the classpath won't spit out the whole thing?  Incidentally, inside PCP, I have something like %stuffa%  and %stuffb% etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that %CLASSPATH%
 contains escaped value of %PCP% so there is string %PCP% instead value of PCP variable.